I am facing EKS RBAC Permissions issue when trying to connect to my aws EKS cluster pods and services using AWS cli
I am facing EKS RBAC Permissions issue when tryng to read pods and services from AWS cli
joelwembo@joelwembo joelwembo % aws eks update-kubeconfig --region us-west-2 --name prodxcloud-tenant-cluster-prod Added new context arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/prodxcloud-tenant-cluster-prod to /Users/joelwembo/.kube/config joelwembo@joelwembo joelwembo % kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system E0802 14:08:54.554750 21333 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
eksctl get iamidentitymapping --cluster prodxcloud-tenant-cluster-prod 

Error: getting auth ConfigMap: Unauthorized
kubectl describe configmap aws-auth -n kube-system 

E0802 14:14:23.117192 23446 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Check below points:

Make sure that you are running latest version of aws cli/eksctl and recommended version of kubectl.
Make sure that the role/user connecting to the cluster has required permission either in aws-auth configmap in kube-system namespace or through EKS access entries.

